# Premier League data scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, hash-map

I have started a project where I am scraping JSON-data from an API. How the scraping is done right now is done in a very repetitive way where the keys of interest are specified and scraped. The data-structure I use is a nested dict to store all the data for each function.

So the steps of each function is straightforward, make a request, iterate through all the data points of interest, store in a dictionary and then write the JSON-file.

I'm looking to see if there is a more efficient way of parsing JSON-data, if I should consider creating functions that handle smaller tasks and if the data-structure of choice is appropriate. The end-game of it all is to create dashboards and analytics so an important function is to be able to link between the datasets, which is supposed to be handled by the different id's for teams, games, fixtures, arenas and so forth. Thank you for taking your time to read, below you will find the full-code.

Many thanks,

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
from tqdm import tqdm

class Premier_league:

    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football'

    def get_competion_id(self):
        competitions = {} #Store all competitions
        league = {} #Store info for each competion
        url = self.base_url + '/competitions' 
        params = (
            ('pageSize', '100'),#adds ?pageSize=100 to url
        )
        response = requests.get(url, params = params).json() # request to obtain the id values and corresponding competition

        all_comps = response["content"]

        #loop to get all info for all competitions
        for comp in all_comps: 

            league[comp["id"]] = comp["description"]

          # creating a stat dict for the player
            competitions[league[comp["id"]]] = {"info":{}}
            competitions[league[comp["id"]]]["info"]["abbreviation"] = comp["abbreviation"]
            competitions[league[comp["id"]]]['info']['id'] = comp['id'] 

        f = open("competitions.json","w")

        # pretty prints and writes the same to the json file 
        f.write(json.dumps(competitions,indent=4, sort_keys=False))
        f.close()

    def get_clubs(self):
        clubs = {} #Store all clubs
        team = {} #Store info for each team
        url = self.base_url + '/clubs' 

        page = 0 #starting value of page
        while True:
            params = (
                ('pageSize', '100'),
                ('page', str(page))#adds ?pageSize=100 to url
                    )
            response = requests.get(url, params = params).json() # request to obtain the team info

            all_clubs = response["content"]


                    #loop to get all info for all competitions
            for club in all_clubs: 
                clubs[club['name']]= club['teams'][0]['id']

                #Unessesary code below, might be of use, produces complex dict-structure
                #team[club["id"]] = club["name"]
                #clubs[team[club["id"]]] = {"info":{}}
                #clubs[team[club["id"]]]['info']['name'] = club["name"]
                #clubs[team[club["id"]]]['info']["id"]= club['teams'][0]['id']

            page += 1
            if page == response["pageInfo"]["numPages"]:
                break

        f = open("clubs.json","w")

        # pretty prints and writes the same to the json file 
        f.write(json.dumps(clubs,indent=4, sort_keys=False))
        f.close()


    def get_fixtures(self,compSeasons):

        fixtures_unplayed = {} #Store info for not played fixtures
        games_unplayed = {} #Store info for not played games

        fixtures_played = {} #Store all clubs
        games_played = {} #Store info for each team
        url = self.base_url + '/fixtures' 


        page = 0 #starting value of page
        while True:
            params = (
                ('pageSize', '100'), #adds ?pageSize=100 to url
                ('page', str(page)),
                ('compSeasons', str(compSeasons)),
                    )
            response = requests.get(url, params = params).json() # request to obtain the team info

            all_games = response["content"]

            #loop to get info for each game 

            for game in tqdm(all_games): 
                if game['status'] == 'U':
                    games_unplayed[game["id"]] = game['id']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]] = {"match":{}}
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['match'] = game['id']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['kickoff'] = game['fixtureType']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['preli_date'] = game['provisionalKickoff']['label']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['scientific_date'] = game['provisionalKickoff']['millis']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['home_team'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['name']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['home_team_id'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['id']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['home_team_abbr'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['abbr']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['away_team'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['name']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['away_team_id'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['id']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['away_team_abbr'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['abbr']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['grounds'] = game['ground']['name']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['grounds_id'] = game['ground']['id']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['gameweek'] = game['gameweek']['gameweek']
                    fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['status'] = game['status']

            for game in tqdm(all_games): 

                if game['status'] == 'C':

                    games_played[game["id"]] = game['id']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]] = {"match":{}}
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['match'] = game['id']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['kickoff'] = game['fixtureType']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['preli_date'] = game['provisionalKickoff']['label']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['scientific_date'] = game['provisionalKickoff']['millis']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['home_team'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['name']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['home_team_id'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['id']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['home_team_abbr'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['abbr']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['home_team_score'] = game['teams'][0]['score']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['away_team'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['name']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['away_team_id'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['id']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['away_team_abbr'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['abbr']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['away_team_score'] = game['teams'][1]['score']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['grounds'] = game['ground']['name']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['grounds_id'] = game['ground']['id']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['gameweek'] = game['gameweek']['gameweek']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['outcome'] = game['outcome']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['extraTime'] = game['extraTime']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['shootout'] = game['shootout']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['played_time'] = game['clock']['secs']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['played_time_label'] = game['clock']['label']
                    fixtures_played[games_played[game["id"]]]['status'] = game['status'] 




            page +=1
            if page == response["pageInfo"]["numPages"]:
                break

        fixtures = dict(fixtures_unplayed)
        fixtures.update(fixtures_played)

        with open("unplayed_fixtures.json","w") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(fixtures_unplayed,indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        with open("played_fixtures.json","w") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(fixtures_played,indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        with open("fixtures.json","w") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(fixtures,indent=4, sort_keys=True))






if __name__ == "__main__":
    prem = Premier_league()
    prem.get_fixtures(274)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple small things I usually do differently that I'd like to point out:

```
f = open("competitions.json","w")

# pretty prints and writes the same to the json file 
f.write(json.dumps(competitions,indent=4, sort_keys=False))
f.close()
```

Can be replaced with:

```
with open("competitions.json","w") as f:
    # pretty prints and writes the same to the json file 
    f.write(json.dumps(competitions,indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

Which prevents leaving files open by accident.

You also do:

```
page = 0 #starting value of page
while True:

    # stuff

    page += 1
    if page == response["pageInfo"]["numPages"]:
        break
```

Which can be replaced by:

```
for page in range(response["pageInfo"]["numPages"]):
```

The assignment of dictionaries can also be done nicer imo. Instead of:

```
games_unplayed[game["id"]] = game['id']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]] = {"match": {}}
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['match'] = game['id']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['kickoff'] = game['fixtureType']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['preli_date'] = game['provisionalKickoff']['label']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['scientific_date'] = game['provisionalKickoff']['millis']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['home_team'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['name']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['home_team_id'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['id']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['home_team_abbr'] = game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['abbr']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['away_team'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['name']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['away_team_id'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['id']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['away_team_abbr'] = game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['abbr']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['grounds'] = game['ground']['name']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['grounds_id'] = game['ground']['id']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['gameweek'] = game['gameweek']['gameweek']
fixtures_unplayed[games_unplayed[game["id"]]]['status'] = game['status']
```

Use:

```
game_id = game['id']
index = games_unplayed[game_id]

fixtures_unplace[index] = \
    {'match': game_id,
     'kickoff': game['fixtureType'],
     'preli_date': game['provisionalKickoff']['label'],
     'scientific_date': game['provisionalKickoff']['millis'],
     'home_team': game['teams'][0]['team']['name'],
     'home_team_id': game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['id'],
     'home_team_abbr': game['teams'][0]['team']['club']['abbr'],
     'away_team': game['teams'][1]['team']['name'],
     'away_team_id': game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['id'],
     'away_team_abbr': game['teams'][1]['team']['club']['abbr'],
     'grounds': game['ground']['name'],
     'grounds_id': game['ground']['id'],
     'gameweek': game['gameweek']['gameweek'],
     'status': game['status']}
```

Lastly, not that important, but I don't like to hardcode values:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.base_url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football'
```

Could also be:

```
def __init__(self, base_url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football'):
    self.base_url = base_url
```

Comment: This is some solid feedback, thank you! The assignment of dictionaries is a real time saver here and it looks really neat. My experience with dicts is really limited and I understand very little about them, so I really appreciate the feedback. Thank you for taking your time to read through everything!

Comment: @MisterButter My pleasure :)